# After setting node type i,e Reliability tier to sliver to bronze on azure service fabric, error on cluster health is waring

Tags: azure, nodes, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

After setting node type i,e Reliability tier to  sliver to bronze on azure service fabric, error on cluster health is waring here below is the error evaluation from service fabric.(Even in vmss of service fabric

Services
 Warning
Unhealthy services: 100% (1/1), ServiceType='ClusterManagerServiceType', MaxPercentUnhealthyServices=0%.
    Service
 Warning
Unhealthy service: ServiceName='fabric:/System/ClusterManagerService', AggregatedHealthState='Warning'.
        Event
 Warning
Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.PLB', Property='ServiceReplicaUnplacedHealth_Secondary_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000002000', HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false.
The Load Balancer was unable to find a placement for one or more of the Service's Replicas:
ClusterManagerServiceName Secondary Partition 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000002000 could not be placed, possibly, due to the following constraints and properties:
TargetReplicaSetSize: 5
Placement Constraint: NodeTypeName==NOde
Depended Service: N/A

Constraint Elimination Sequence:
ReplicaExclusionStatic eliminated 2 possible node(s) for placement -- 1/3 node(s) remain.
ReplicaExclusionDynamic eliminated 1 possible node(s) for placement -- 0/3 node(s) remain.

Nodes Eliminated By Constraints:

### ReplicaExclusionStatic -- No Colocations with Partition's Existing Secondaries/Instances:

FaultDomain:fd:/0 NodeName:_NOde_0 NodeType:NOde NodeTypeName:NOde UpgradeDomain:0 UpgradeDomain: ud:/0 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None
FaultDomain:fd:/2 NodeName:_NOde_2 NodeType:NOde NodeTypeName:NOde UpgradeDomain:2 UpgradeDomain: ud:/2 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None

### ReplicaExclusionDynamic -- No Colocations with Partition's Existing Primary or Potential Secondaries:

FaultDomain:fd:/1 NodeName:_NOde_1 NodeType:NOde NodeTypeName:NOde UpgradeDomain:1 UpgradeDomain: ud:/1 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None

Help me to slove this problem

Answer (score 2):

When you create your cluster with [Reliability tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity#the-reliability-characteristics-of-the-cluster) Silver it will provision 5 replicas of the system services, i.e. the services that essentially are Service Fabric.

Downgrading from Silver to Bronze means that you change the target replica count of these services from 5 to 3.

In order for SF to *place* replicas on nodes it evaluates a set of constraints, on of these being that it does not want two replicas of the same service partition to end up on the same node.

As it looks from your error you have one Node Type with 3 nodes in it but you still have Silver reliabilty tier, that means that SF is unable to find a node for the last two of your replicas for the system services (in your log it is `System/ClusterManagerService`, but same applies for all system services).

Make sure that your cluster has at least as many nodes as your reliability tier needs, i.e. 3 nodes for a Bronze tier, 5 for a Silver and so on.

Also, what you are seeing is a *warning* that the cluster is not able to uphold it's characteristics, but it should still be running, right?

Comment: @yope  thank you for your response ..   yes the its running even application running in fabric is working fine :)